# clojure - strng-concat with group by in sequences of maps

Tags: clojure

Given input data from a jdbc source such as this:

```
  (def input-data
    [{:doc_id 1 :doc_seq 1  :doc_content "this is a very long "}
    {:doc_id 1 :doc_seq 2  :doc_content "sentence from a mainframe "}
    {:doc_id 1 :doc_seq 3  :doc_content "system that was built before i was "}
    {:doc_id 1 :doc_seq 4  :doc_content "born."}
    {:doc_id 2 :doc_seq 1  :doc_content "this is a another very long "}
    {:doc_id 2 :doc_seq 2  :doc_content "sentence from the same mainframe "}
    {:doc_id 3 :doc_seq 1  :doc_content "Ok here we are again. "}
    {:doc_id 3 :doc_seq 2  :doc_content "The mainframe only had 40 char per field so"}
    {:doc_id 3 :doc_seq 3  :doc_content "they broke it into multiple rows "}
    {:doc_id 3 :doc_seq 4  :doc_content "which seems to be common"}
    {:doc_id 3 :doc_seq 5  :doc_content " for the time. "}
    {:doc_id 3 :doc_seq 6  :doc_content "thanks for your help."}])
```

I want to group by `doc id`, and string-concat the `doc_content`, so my output would look like this:

```
  [{:doc_id 1 :doc_content "this is a very long sentence from a mainfram system that was built before i was born."}
   {:doc_id 2 :doc_content "this is a another very long sentence ... clip..."}
   {:doc_id 3 :doc_content "... clip..."}]
```

I was thinking of using `group-by` however that outputs a map, and I need to
output something lazy as the input data set could be very large.  Maybe I could run `group-by` and some compbination of `reduce-kv` to get what i'm looking for... or maybe something with `frequencies` if i can coerce it to be lazy.

I can guarantee that it will be sorted; I will put the order by (through sql) on `doc_id`, and `doc_seq`, so the only thing this program is responsible for is the aggregate/string-concat part.  I will likely have large input data for the whole sequence, but a specific `doc_id` in that sequence should only be a few dozen `doc_seq`.

Any tips appreciated,

Comment: Why do you want to concatenate it (in-memory) at all instead of just sending it to wherever it needs to be sent? (stdout?)

Comment: I'm trying to translate a mainframe system that couldn't fit many strings in the last column into something eventually such as a seq of many json values.... does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`partition-by` is lazy, and as long as each *doc sequence* fits in memory, this should work:

```
(defn collapse-docs [docs]
  (apply merge-with
         (fn [l r]
           (if (string? r)
             (str l r)
             r))
         docs))

(sequence ;; you may want to use eduction here, depending on use case
  (comp
    (partition-by :doc_id)
    (map collapse-docs))
  input-data)
=>
({:doc_id 1,
  :doc_seq 4,
  :doc_content "this is a very long sentence from a mainframe system that was built before i was born."}
  {:doc_id 2, :doc_seq 2, :doc_content "this is a another very long sentence from the same mainframe "}
  {:doc_id 3,
   :doc_seq 6,
   :doc_content "Ok here we are again. The mainframe only had 40 char per field sothey broke it into multiple rows which seems to be common for the time. thanks for your help."})
```

Comment: This is great, thanks.  `partition-by` was what i was looking for.  FYI, my docs will all fit into memory (probaly at most 5mb each) but I could have a few million of them, so i'll have to pay attention to how the memory gets allocated when this ends up on spark.